Finding the optimal surface enclosing a given volume
I would like to find, over the set of continuous surfaces that enclose a volume $V$, the one(s) that lead to the maximal value of a certain cost function. I'm working on a physics problem which involves solving a wave equation inside such a volume, subject to boundary conditions (I've been looking at Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions but I'm interested in looking at others as well).
Suppose we're doing acoustics, in which case the wave solution would be a scalar-valued function $p(t,x,y,z)$ that tells you the pressure at each point $(x, y, z)$ in space at time $t$. If we take the temporal Fourier transform, we get $P(\omega, x, y, z)$. What I would like to do next is evaluate the integral $$ \int_{a}^{b} \mathrm{log}(f(P(\omega, x, y, z))) \mathrm{d}\omega,$$
where $f$ is a given function. For a fixed point $(x, y, z)$, what shape of the enclosing surface would maximize this integral? Can we ensure that changing the point wouldn't also lead to a different maximizing surface?

What does the surface have to do with the quantity you are maximizing? It seems like it only concerns the PDE solution at a specific points and the PDE (wave equation) doesn't seem like it has anything to do with the surface. Could you proviude some more details as to how the objective function, PDE, and manifold are connected?

The objective function is dependent on $P(\omega,x,y,z)$, which is dependent on the surface via boundary conditions. For instance, consider that enforcing Dirichlet boundary conditions over a box will lead to one $P(\omega,x,y,z)$ and having Dirichlet boundary conditions over a sphere will lead to a different $P(\omega,x,y,z)$.
